# Add titles and remove numbering in subfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have this 6x3 subfloats and I want to add vertical titles to each row of them and horizontal titles to each column. I also want to remove these `(a) (b) (c) ...` labels so that it's only the caption like the first row of captions in my figure would be `0.2` `0.2` `0.3` instead of `(a) 0.2` `(b) 0.2` `(c) 0.3`. If anyone could please advise how this can be done.

This is my figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth {a.png}}\label{a}
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{b.png}}\label{b}
\subfloat[0.3]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{c.png}}\label{c}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d.png}}\label{d}
\subfloat[0.4]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{e.png}}\label{e}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{f.png}}\label{f}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{g.png}}\label{g}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{h.png}}\label{h}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{i.png}}\label{i}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{j.png}}\label{j}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{k.png}}\label{k}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{l.png}}\label{l}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{m.png}}\label{m}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{n.png}}\label{n}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{o.png}}\label{o}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{p.png}}\label{p}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{q.png}}\label{q}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{r.png}}\label{r}
\caption{results}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

EDIT:

Just to clarify how my end result should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing sacred, or even particularly useful, with \subfloat or \subfigure.

I'm not sure what you intended to accomplish with the \labels.  If you don't want the (a) - (r) to appear, having \ref{r} expand as (r) is not particularly useful.  If you want to create hyperlinks, there is always \hypertarget and \hyperlink.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempdima}
\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempdima][c]{\textbf{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\centering%
\begin{figure}
\settoheight{\tempdima}{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }c@{}}
&\textbf{Trial A} & \textbf{Trial B} & \textbf{Trial C} \\
\rowname{Exp 1}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.2 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\
\rowname{Exp 2}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.5 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
\rowname{Exp 3}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.5 & 0.5 & 0.7 \\
\rowname{Exp 4}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7 \\
\rowname{Exp 5}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7 \\
\rowname{Exp 6}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&0.5 & 0.6 & 0.7
\end{tabular}
\caption{results}%
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular images]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please check the updated question? As I think you forgot to mention the "headings" part. Thank you.

Comment: Revisions implemented, although you seem to have figured it out yourself.  Also, the figure is too tall for the page, at least using the defaults.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What if I wanted to apply these titles on rows and columns of my example? Like with normal labels `(a)` `(b)` `(c)`,.... if you could please advise. I posted a new question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239715/add-titles-for-rows-and-columns-in-a-subfloat

Comment: And also do you know how I can force the figure to fit in my page?

Comment: The easiest way is to reduce the .32\linewidth.  You should be getting a warning message, or use the [draft] option for memoir.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you please check my other question?