# Add titles for rows and columns in a subfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have this 6x3 subfloats and I want to add vertical titles to each row of them and horizontal titles to each column.If anyone could please advise how this can be done. I also want to fit this figure in one page.

This is my figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth {a.png}}\label{a}
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{b.png}}\label{b}
\subfloat[0.3]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{c.png}}\label{c}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{d.png}}\label{d}
\subfloat[0.4]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{e.png}}\label{e}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{f.png}}\label{f}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{g.png}}\label{g}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{h.png}}\label{h}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{i.png}}\label{i}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{j.png}}\label{j}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{k.png}}\label{k}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{l.png}}\label{l}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{m.png}}\label{m}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{n.png}}\label{n}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{o.png}}\label{o}\\
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{p.png}}\label{p}
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{q.png}}\label{q}
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{r.png}}\label{r}
\caption{results}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Where's the difference with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239602/add-titles-and-remove-numbering-in-subfloat?

Comment: @Ignasi the difference is that here I don't want to remove the captions labels. I also want to know how to fit a big image in one page.

Comment: Then, I think you should start with the accepted answer in your previous question and only ask "how to fit this in ope page" because the first part of your question is already solved.

Comment: In any case It would be good that you include `complete` examples and not just snippets. If you show us which `\documentclass` ans packages are you using, it's easier to help you. Please read what's a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @Ignasi The first part is not solved. In the other question I wanted to delete (remove) the captions labels `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`,... here I don't want to.

Comment: @Ignasi I've also added now the document class in my question

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your comment. could you please explain or post an answer?

Comment: If you aren't using memoir, which package is \subfloat coming from?

Comment: I'm using the `subfloat` package

Comment: There is no \subfloat in the subfloat package.

Comment: \usepackage{float}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{xtocinc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changebar}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}

Comment: @JohnKormylo above are all the packages used in my document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since \captionof uses \par and \vskip, you can't use it in a tabular.  It's easier just to write your own caption macro, so long as you don't want all these subfloats showing up in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempdima}
\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempdima][c]{\textbf{#1}}}}

\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]% #1 = caption
{\refstepcounter{subfigure}\textbf{(\thesubfigure) }{\ignorespaces #1}}

\begin{document}
\centering%
\begin{figure}
\settoheight{\tempdima}{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
\centering\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{ }c@{ }c@{ }c@{}}
&\textbf{Trial A} & \textbf{Trial B} & \textbf{Trial C} \\
\rowname{Exp 1}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.2} & \mycaption{0.2} & \mycaption{0.3}\\
\rowname{Exp 2}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.4} & \mycaption{0.6}\\
\rowname{Exp 3}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.7} \\
\rowname{Exp 4}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.6} & \mycaption{0.7} \\
\rowname{Exp 5}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.6} & \mycaption{0.7} \\
\rowname{Exp 6}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[-1ex]
&\mycaption{0.5} & \mycaption{0.6} & \mycaption{0.7} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{results}%
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabualr captions]

---

Yes, it is possible to implement this without using a tabular.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{\textbf{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{.3\linewidth}
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\centering
\hspace{\baselineskip}
\columnname{Test A}\hfil
\columnname{Test B}\hfil
\columnname{Test C}\\
\rowname{Exp 1}
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{a}\hfil
\subfloat[0.2]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{b}\hfil
\subfloat[0.3]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{c}\\
\rowname{Exp 2}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{d}\hfil
\subfloat[0.4]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{e}\hfil
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{f}\\
\rowname{Exp 3}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{g}\hfil
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{h}\hfil
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{i}\\
\rowname{Exp 4}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{j}\hfil
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{k}\hfil
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{l}\\
\rowname{Exp 5}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{m}\hfil
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{n}\hfil
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{o}\\
\rowname{Exp 6}
\subfloat[0.5]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-a}}\label{p}\hfil
\subfloat[0.6]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-b}}\label{q}\hfil
\subfloat[0.7]{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{example-image-c}}\label{r}
\caption{results}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: subfloat with column and row names]

---

While preparing this \hfil demo I discovered things aren't quite as simple as I thought.  Specifically, \\ and \newline seem to add some additional space to the right, rather than just an \hfil.  After \centering, however, \\ loses the extra space (but not \newline).

The last thing to remember is that since all the \hfils in one line expand to the same size, if the stuff between the \hfils are not the same size then they will not be precisely aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\hfil\fbox{centered}\linebreak[4]
\hfil\fbox{skewed}\\
\indent\hfil\fbox{recentered}\\
\hfil\fbox{two}\hfil\fbox{columns}\linebreak[4]
\hfil\fbox{now}\hfil\fbox{three}\hfil\fbox{columns}\linebreak[4]
\centering\fbox{centered}\\
\fbox{skewed}\newline
\fbox{two}\hfil\fbox{columns}\\
\fbox{now}\hfil\fbox{three}\hfil\fbox{columns}\\
\fbox{left}\hfill\fbox{center}\hfill\fbox{right}\\
\leavevmode\rlap{\fbox{left}}\hfill\fbox{center}\hfill\llap{\fbox{right}}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what if I have only one figure per row and I only want to put the rows names and no column name? I've tried doing this `\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{\linewidth}
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{res2.png}}%
\centering
\hspace{\baselineskip}
\rowname{Exp 1}` but its not working properly. It display the row name in the middle on the line and then under it the pic and so on...would you please advise? and would you like me to open a new question?

Comment: Opening a new question would probably be best.  Otherwise I'll have to ask a lot of questions like "Did you add a blank line between \rowname and the first picture?"

Comment: I've opened a new question found in this link so if you could please check it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240082/add-titles-to-only-rows-using-subfloat

Comment: I'm using the second solution. What if I want to shift the column headers to the right or the left a little bit? I mean how I can control this? The reason I'm asking is because I'm using the same idea with two columns instead of three, so I have two columns, but their positions are not correct. So if you could please advise.

Comment: \hfil and \hfill are typically used to space things (like \subfloats) evenly across the page.  For example, \centering is equivalent to placing an \hfil a the start and (if needed) end of each line.  Basically, every \hfil in a line expands to the same size.

Comment: Could you please explain it to me by showing it to me in the example I wrote in this question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241912/align-headers-of-subfloats-correctly