# Add Titles to only Rows using subfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats

Following the answer found in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239715/add-titles-for-rows-and-columns-in-a-subfloat) , I've tried to use the below code to add titles to only the rows, but what happens is that the title appears in a line then the picture in the line under and so on. So if anyone could please advise.

These are the packages used:

```
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{newlfont} 
\usepackage{xtocinc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{changebar} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{subfloat} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newlength{\tempdima}
\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempdima][c]{\textbf{#1}}}}

\newcounter{subfigure}[figure]
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]% #1 = caption
{\refstepcounter{subfigure}\textbf{(\thesubfigure) }{\ignorespaces #1}}
```

This is my figure:

```
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{\linewidth}
\settoheight{\tempheight}{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic1.png}}%
\centering
\hspace{\baselineskip}
\rowname{Exp 1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic2.png}}\label{pic1}\\
\rowname{Exp 2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic3.png}}\label{pic2}\\
\rowname{Exp 3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic4.png}}\label{pic3}\\
\rowname{Exp 4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic5.png}}\label{pic4}\\
\rowname{Exp 5}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\tempwidth]{pic6.png}}\label{pic5}
\caption{This is the caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: A full MWE (Minimal Working Example) can be copied and used by anyone.  Please add in the \documentclass, \usepackages, custom macro definitions and use images files from the mwe package.  Use my previous answers as a guide.

Comment: Okay. I will now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the image is just too big.  For this problem, the limiting dimension is the height, not the width.  (Come to think of it, this was also true in the original question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{\textbf{#1}}}}

\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempheight}{0.18\textheight}
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image}}% not needed without \columnname
\centering
\rowname{Exp 1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image}}\label{pic1}\\
\rowname{Exp 2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image-a}}\label{pic2}\\
\rowname{Exp 3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image-b}}\label{pic3}\\
\rowname{Exp 4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image-C}}\label{pic4}\\
\rowname{Exp 5}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image}}\label{pic5}
\caption{This is the caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```