# Align Headers of subfloats correctly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I'm using the following code but the columns headers are not aligned in the center of the columns, so if anyone could please advise:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\centering%

\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempheight}{0.15\textheight}
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{\includegraphics[height=\tempheight]{example-image-a}}%
\centering
\hspace{\baselineskip}
\columnname{Without Results}
\columnname{With Results}\\
\rowname{Row 1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\label{1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\label{11}\\
\rowname{Row 2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\label{2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-d}}\label{22}\\
\rowname{Row 3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-e}}\label{3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-f}}\label{33}\\
\rowname{Row 4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-g}}\label{4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-h}}\label{44}
\caption{capt1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\tempheight` and `\tempwidth` went all wrong. With some fine tuning, we get this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mwe,subfig,calc}

\newlength{\tempheight}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\tempheight][c]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\columnname}[1]% #1 = text
{\makebox[\tempwidth][c]{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\centering%

\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempheight}{\heightof{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}
\setlength{\tempwidth}{0.48\linewidth}%
\centering
\hspace{0.52\baselineskip}
\columnname{Without Results}
\columnname{With Results}\\
\rowname{Row 1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\label{1}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\label{11}\\
\rowname{Row 2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\label{2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\label{22}\\
\rowname{Row 3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\label{3}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}\label{33}\\
\rowname{Row 4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image}}\label{4}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\label{44}
\caption{capt1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, since you are not using `subcaption`s, you may use `tabular` as well.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,calc}

\newlength{\tempheight}

\setlength{\tempheight}{\heightof{\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}}}

\newcommand{\rowname}[1]% #1 = text
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\tempheight}{\centering #1}}}


\begin{document}
\centering%

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
& Without Results & With Results\\
\rowname{Row 1} &\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
& \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
\rowname{Row 2} &
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-c} &
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
\rowname{Row 3} &
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\
\rowname{Row 4}&
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{tabular}
\caption{capt1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]