# How to center text in figure with subfigs

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subfig

Say that I have this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\textbf{Text I want centered} \\
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \\
{\centering \textbf{Text to be centered}} \\
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \\
{\centering \textbf{Center me}} \\
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \\
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to center the text above each set of three figures. The first one doesn't work because I didn't try to center it. However, I expected the second and third to be centered because I put them in a `{\centering }` code fragment. Is there a way to center them? The text does not need to be coded as it is if there are better ways (like maybe subheaders or something).

Comment: Can this text be several lines long?

Comment: I prefer to use tabulars to mix text and images, possibly using \subcaption.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239715/add-titles-for-rows-and-columns-in-a-subfloat/239809?r=SearchResults&s=26|11.1446#239809

Comment: @Bernard, yes, it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i understood your question, you looking for  the following soltion:

[image]

which is generated by:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\textbf{Text I want centered}

\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}} \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\textbf{Text to be centered}

\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\textbf{Center me}

\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}  \hfill
\subfloat[Image]{\label{}\includegraphics[width=42mm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```